# Out-of-the-bag for random forest - practical implementation

Tags: random-forest, error

I’m reading about out-of-the-bag error estimate and I quite understand the method itself, but I’m not sure if I have the right idea about how it is done in practice.

I have to remember which samples from the training set went to which tree, and after training RF for each sample I get “subforest” (trees that didn’t see that sample during training), make prediction, calculate average error. I repeat this for each sample and average the resulting error averages. So I have to:
1. Numerate the trees and be able to access them by index, right? This actually doesn’t seem like a problem, a list can be used, right?
2. I have to remember which sample didn’t go to some trees. Is the space complexity $O(t * n)$ for $t$ trees and $n$ training samples? Should I have a set for each training sample, holding indices of the trees that didn’t have it?